# Intel Mobile 4 Series Integrated Graphics Controller

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics, tearing

When I run the `inxi -G` command on drivers I get `(unloaded:fbdev,vesa)` and I also have screen tearing. Is it correct that in "driver" it has to say "Intel" in my case, right?

Results of `inxi -G`:

```
Graphics:  Card: Intel Mobile 4 Series Integrated Graphics Controller
           Display Server: X.Org 1.19.6 drivers: (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 1366x768@59.97hz
           GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Mobile Intel GM45 Express x86/MMX/SSE2
           GLX Version: 2.1 Mesa 18.0.5
```

And with lspci -nnk I get this:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub [8086:2a40] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Dell Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub [1028:02aa]
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:2a42] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Dell Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller [1028:02aa]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
00:02.1 Display controller [0380]: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:2a43] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Dell Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller [1028:02aa]
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 [8086:2937] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Dell 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller [1028:02aa]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1a.1 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 [8086:2938] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Dell 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller [1028:02aa]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1a.2 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 [8086:2939] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Dell 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller [1028:02aa]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1a.7 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 [8086:293c] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Dell 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller [1028:02aa]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller [8086:293e] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Dell 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller [1028:02aa]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 [8086:2940] (rev 03)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 2 [8086:2942] (rev 03)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 3 [8086:2944] (rev 03)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 5 [8086:2948] (rev 03)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 [8086:2934] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Dell 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller [1028:02aa]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1d.1 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 [8086:2935] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Dell 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller [1028:02aa]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1d.2 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 [8086:2936] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Dell 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller [1028:02aa]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1d.7 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 [8086:293a] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Dell 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller [1028:02aa]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1e.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge [8086:2448] (rev 93)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation ICH9M LPC Interface Controller [8086:2919] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Dell ICH9M LPC Interface Controller [1028:02aa]
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 82801IBM/IEM (ICH9M/ICH9M-E) 4 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:2929] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Dell 82801IBM/IEM (ICH9M/ICH9M-E) 4 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [1028:02aa]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller [8086:2930] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Dell 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller [1028:02aa]
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8040 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller [11ab:4354] (rev 13)
    Subsystem: Dell 88E8040 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller [1028:02aa]
    Kernel driver in use: sky2
    Kernel modules: sky2
0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:000c]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: ssb, wl
```

Comment: I've noticed inxi sometimes shows strange or incomplete info. Try `lspci -nnk` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I  just putted the result of that comand. I don't speak english very well so you may note some or many syntact and orthography errors.

Comment: As expected, it says "    Kernel driver in use: i915". Unlike inxi, that command show drivers in use. Also, you can copy/paste outputs.